# Screen on when charging on powered off phone

Tags: battery, charging, screen, lineageos

## The issue

My phone's screen is always on when I charge it while it is turned off.
It displays this image:

[image]

And the screen cannot be turned off. I believe it is not charging either, but I can boot it normally. It charges normally when on.

---

## Specification

- Image installed: [lineage-17.1-20201012-UNOFFICIAL-treble_a64_bvS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/andyyan-gsi/files/lineage-17.x/)
- Build number: treble_a64_bvS-userdebug 10 QQ3A.200805.001 eng.crossg.20201012.051017 test-keys
- Phone: [Blackview BV 5500 Pro](https://promo.blackview.hk/blackview-bv5500-pro-budget-rugged-smartphone/)

---

## Similar issues

I believe the issues posted at

- https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/help/power-off-charging-lineage-os-14-1-t3694182
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/lineage/help/charging-screen-misbehaving-phone-off-t3611714

are fairly similar, but do no have a solution, as far as I can tell.

---

## What I've tried

Originally, I had the message

> Orange State
> Your device has been unlocked and can't be trusted..Your device will boot in 5 seconds

Displayed along the picture of the battery. The phone would not boot (unless I've pushed the on button, that is), but the message would continually be displayed.

I've followed the tutorial at https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-31664.html and removed the 5 seconds boot delay time in Orange State: I don't see that warning when I turn off my phone or when it is turned off and charging, but the screen still stays on when I'm charging the phone turned off.